# Dataweave1.0 removing nested elements

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have two json payloads, the first contains mapping details and the second contains actual data that needs to be transformed as per the mapping payload

Mapping Payload:

```
[
  {
    "SourceField": "CUSTOMER_NAME",
    "DestinationField": "Customer"
  },
  {
    "SourceField": "PROJECT_ID",
    "DestinationField": "ProjectID"
  }
]
```

Actual Data payload

```
[
  {
    "CUSTOMER_NAME":"Smith",
    "PROJECT_ID": 12345
  },
  {
    "CUSTOMER_NAME":"James",
    "PROJECT_ID": 34563
  }
]
```

I'm trying to get an output as

```
[
 {
   "Customer":"Smith",
   "ProjectID": 12345
 },
 {
   "Customer":"James",
   "ProjectID":34563
 }
]
```

DW Code

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var mappingPayload = MappingPayload as in above example
%var actualData = ActualDataPayload as in above example
%var mappings = mappingPayload reduce ((env, obj={}) -> obj ++ {(env.SourceField):(env.DestinationField)})
---
actualData map ((object,index)->{
    (index):object mapObject (value,key)->{
        (mappings[key]):value
    }
})
```

[image: Sample code and output]

The problem with the current output is that I am able to map the content to expected key but it is nested in index, any suggestions to get rid of the nested element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an object at the top level, just make it an array with `(` and `)`.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var mappingPayload = [
  {
    "SourceField": "CUSTOMER_NAME",
    "DestinationField": "Customer"
  },
  {
    "SourceField": "PROJECT_ID",
    "DestinationField": "ProjectID"
  }
]

%var actualData = [
  {
    "CUSTOMER_NAME":"Smith",
    "PROJECT_ID": 12345
  },
  {
    "CUSTOMER_NAME":"James",
    "PROJECT_ID": 34563
  }
]

%var mappings = mappingPayload reduce ((env, obj={}) -> obj ++ {(env.SourceField):(env.DestinationField)})
---
actualData map (
    $ mapObject {
        (mappings[$$]): $
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var mappingPayload = [
  {
    "SourceField": "CUSTOMER_NAME",
    "DestinationField": "Customer"
  },
  {
    "SourceField": "PROJECT_ID",
    "DestinationField": "ProjectID"
  }
]
%var actualData = [
  {
    "CUSTOMER_NAME":"Smith",
    "PROJECT_ID": 12345
  },
  {
    "CUSTOMER_NAME":"James",
    "PROJECT_ID": 34563
  }
]

%var mappings = mappingPayload reduce ((env, obj={}) -> obj ++ {(env.SourceField):(env.DestinationField)}) 
---
actualData map ((object,index)->{

a:object mapObject (value,key)->{(mappings[key]):value}
}.a)
```

Answer (score 0):

To your existing approach

```
actualData map ((object,index)->{

(index):object mapObject (value,key)->{(mappings[key]):value}
}reduce (index))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
actualData map ((object,index) -> {
   (index):object mapObject (value,key) -> {(mappings[key]):value}
}
```

Do this:

```
actualData map ((object,index) -> {
   (object mapObject (value,key) -> {(mappings[key]):value})
}
```